# Не понятны основы тэгов в оптимизации сайта

Tags: seo

Вопрос заключается в следующем
.
При попытке привязать на главную страницу с меню каноническую сылку про нас , 
я хотел бы получить результат индексирования заглавной станицы с оптимизированым текстом из истории про нас.
Будет ли это работать вообще ?
Мой вэвсайт www.aleksandrs.lv

Comment: нет, это не работает. И ссылку лучше убрать.

Comment: Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Или наймите нормальных сеошников (которые напудрят мозги, возьмут денежки и скажут, что будет круто), или просто наполняйте нормальным контентом. Делайте нормальный сайт.  К примеру, если страницу сузить до 600 пикселей, то пункты "меню" пропадают. Если подергать страницу - то оно появится. И да, добавьте https - вот это очень хорошо помогает сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Гугл, и вероятно другие поисковые системы, будут индексировать содержание только сканируемой веб-страницы. В вашем случае это стартовая веб-страница, которая имеет **[тонкое содержание](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)** и это может оказать негативное влияние на поисковый ранг вашего веб-сайта:

> **Бесполезный контент**.
>   На вашем сайте обнаружены некачественные или малоинформативные
>   страницы.

Для связи ваших веб-страниц используйте **[структуру иерархии веб-сайта](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184)**:

> **Иерархия сайта**.
>   Узнайте, как поисковые системы используют URL.
>
> Поисковым системам нужен
>   отдельный URL для каждого фрагмента контента, чтобы иметь возможность
>   просканировать, проиндексировать его и показать его пользователям. Для
>   разных фрагментов контента (например, для разных товаров или для
>   региональных вариантов и переводов на другие языки) следует
>   использовать разные URL, чтобы в результатах поиска не возникало
>   путаницы.

Проверьте **[следующую информацию Гугл о канонических ссылках](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)**:

> Для чего выбирать канонический URL? Указывать каноническую страницу из
>   числа одинаковых или похожих стоит в следующих случаях: **Если нужно
>   выбрать, какой URL следует показывать в результатах поиска**.